# HP Deskjet f300 Printer not printing documents

Tags: 11.10, printing

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 my printer - an HP deskjet F300 series - will no longer print from any word processor, including gedit.  The scanner still functions and I can print emails.  It was working correctly with TextMaker, LibreOffice and Gedit before the upgrade

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my Deskjet d2660. The solution was to download and install the [latest drivers](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html) directly from the HP's site.

The download dialog may tell you that Ubuntu already has the correct driver for your printer, nevertheless, download and install it anyway.

Comment: Peter, Thanks for this pertinent info. I have my entire family and many many friends switched over to Ubuntu through the years and Ive always recommended HP printers. Ever since Ubuntu 12.04 LTS their printers have either stopped working or take 30 minutes to spit something out. I will give your solution a try, thanks.

Comment: HP printer problems fixed! The newest HPLIP software did the job. you can download here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html