# Newly Installed Printer says "Idle - Rendering completed"

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to connect my printer, an HP Deskjet F300 via USB.  I used the Printers software included to install the suggested drivers (HP DeskJet 9300 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11).  It says it is connected and when I ask it to print something (LibreOffice, a Test Page from CUPS or the Printers), it says, "Processing" then the job disappears from the pending jobs as if it has printed, but nothing has printed.  Instead, I see, "Idle - Rendering completed" under the printer state.  I tried finding the issue and think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm not using HP ink (third party ink from Amazon) but have no idea how to fix it.

I have already also tried installing from this page, but that did nothing. http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html

Comment: As a side note, this computer came with Windows 7 prior to my installing Ubuntu, and the printer worked fine then, so I don't think it is the printer that is the problem, but of course, can't rule it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HP Deskjet f300 Printer not printing documents](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75090/hp-deskjet-f300-printer-not-printing-documents)

Comment: NOT a duplicate.